# Can I map Fn-h, Fn-j, Fn-k, and Fn-l to the arrow keys?

Tags: laptop, vim, wayland, swaywm

Anybody who uses vim would understand the motivation immediately.

By "Fn", I am referring to the key on laptops that switches between F1, F2, etc. and volume up, volume down etc.

This would be on linux in wayland, particularly sway.

It should be possible.
I checked wev, and my Fn key does generate "XF86WakeUp" key events all on its own, without having to press any other keys.

Comment: Autohotkey can probably do it. Not exactly sure how though.

Comment: I use Vim and I don't understand the motivation.

Comment: The motivation is this would allow you to use the bindings in a GUI editor. Seems pretty obvious and also very useful.